# Suggestion for a efficient Pagination tutorial?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have looped data from mysql, and it's a pretty long list. What's the most efficient way to do pagination? Currently, I am looking at this one: http://www.evolt.org/node/19340

Feel free to recommend a better one, thanks !

Comment: Looks like a bit of a mess, but the ideas are all there. You should be able to clean it up a bit ;) Good project for ya! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than fetching everything from the DB like in the article, you could just SELECT the rows you can actually display - ie. if you have 10 items per page, just select 10 - and then selecting the total amount of rows. If the DB is large this can be much more efficient even though it's two queries.

Comment: I believe LIMIT is the word you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Like Sorin Mocanu said, if you want to order the result by some criteria, maybe modified time or some frequency, then sorting will be a big performance penalty. Even though you only need 10 records, you still need to sort all(maybe millions of) records, unless you make sure index is used and is used correctly.

Here is an excellent article regarding pagination with mysql:
http://www.percona.com/ppc2009/PPC2009_mysql_pagination.pdf

Or from mysql website:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the example in the book Wicked Cool PHP as my starting point. Very neat and well explained IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE condition = true ORDER BY some_field LIMIT 100, 10
```

Where 100 is the number of records to skip and 10 is the number of rows to retrieve.
Make sure you have an index covering `condition` and the order criteria fields if you want to have the maximum performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really nice function/class to have as part of your standard library. I would strongly recommend you roll your own along these lines:

- Query to work out total items (rows).
- Code to work out upper & lower limit based on number of items you want to display per page.
- Second query LIMIT'ed accordingly.

I'd post some code, but that would take the fun out of it :)